# Convert memorystream to double-array?

Tags: c#, fft, memorystream, naudio

I've got a pcm-stream of raw music data from a wave-file and would like to convert it to a double-array (to apply a fft afterwards).

The result I got now contains very high or low double-numbers (1.0E-200 and 1.0E+300) and I'm not sure whether these can be correct.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
WaveStream pcm = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3);
double[] real = new double[pcm.Length];
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
int count = 0;

while ((read = pcm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
   real[count] = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, 0);
   count++;
}
```

Comment: I don't know audio streams, but maybe either you actually want to convert each byte of audio data into a double, or it could be an issue of big-endian vs little-endian ? If so, you would need to reverse each group of 8 bytes before converting to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PCM stream is almost certainly 16 bit. So instead of `BitConverter.ToDouble` use `ToInt16` instead. Then divide by 32768.0 to get into the the range +/- 1.0

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is old; however, I thought I might offer this alternative approach to calling BitConverter.ToDouble.

```
    public static double[] ToDoubleArray(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        Debug.Assert(bytes.Length % sizeof(double) == 0, "byte array must be aligned on the size of a double.");

        double[] doubles = new double[bytes.Length / sizeof(double)];
        GCHandle pinnedDoubles = GCHandle.Alloc(doubles, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pinnedDoubles.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bytes.Length);
        pinnedDoubles.Free();
        return doubles;
    }

    public static double[] ToDoubleArray(this MemoryStream stream)
    {
        return stream.ToArray().ToDoubleArray();
    }
```